# Keep getting FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1 when trying to do insert query from android app to amazon

Tags: android

I would like to run an async task to insert data into my amazon rds using an amazon lambda.  It worked a few times and now I'm getting errors.  The first one is:

ERROR:

```
 --------- beginning of crash
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1

 The second one is: 
W/System.err: java.io.IOException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or 
directory)
              at java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:939)
```

I have permissions is my manifest file.  Why am I getting these errors? Thanks!

Private class DBTask extends AsyncTask{
  public LambdaInvokerFactory credentialsProvider(){
        CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider cognitoProvider = new CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider(
                BarcodeActivity.this.getApplicationContext(),
                "xxxxxx",
                "xxxxxx",
                "xxxxxx",
                "xxxx",
                Regions.US_EAST_1 );

```
    // Create LambdaInvokerFactory, to be used to instantiate the Lambda proxy.
    LambdaInvokerFactory factory = new LambdaInvokerFactory( BarcodeActivity.this.getApplicationContext(),
                                                             Regions.US_EAST_1, cognitoProvider );
    return factory;
}

private void getVehicle ( Vehicle veh ) {
    System.out.println( "IN GET VEHICLE: " + veh.getRfidtag() );
    DBTask task = new DBTask( veh );
    task.execute();
    try {
        Thread.sleep( 5000 );
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

private class DBTask extends AsyncTask {
    ProgressDialog dialog;

```
    CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider cognitoProvider = new CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider(
           BarcodeActivity.this.getApplication(), "us-east-1:2a880431-f082-4704-a864-c2ab621be94c", Regions.US_EAST_1 );


    // Create LambdaInvokerFactory, to be used to instantiate the Lambda proxy.
    LambdaInvokerFactory factory = new LambdaInvokerFactory( BarcodeActivity.this.getApplicationContext(),
                                                             Regions.US_EAST_1, cognitoProvider );
    final AWSInterface myInterface = factory.build( AWSInterface.class );
    private Vehicle v;
    public DBTask ( Vehicle veh ) {
       v=veh;
    }
    String m="hi";

  /*  @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // Set up progress dialog
        super.onPreExecute();
        dialog = new ProgressDialog(BarcodeActivity.this);
       dialog.setMessage("adding...");
       dialog.setCancelable( false );
        dialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
        dialog.show();

    }*/
    @Override
    protected ResponseClass doInBackground ( Vehicle... vehicles ) {

        try{
            Log.e("tag","in try statment "+ v);

           return myInterface.volvoinventoryfunc(v);
        }catch(LambdaFunctionException lfe){
            Log.e( "Tag", "Failed to invoke echo", lfe );
            return null;
        }

    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute ( ResponseClass result ) {
        dialog.dismiss();
      //  if (result == null) {
       //     return;
      //  }

        // Do a toast
      //  Toast.makeText( BarcodeActivity.this, result.getGreetings(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
        super.onPostExecute(result);

    }
}
```

Comment: IOException some file or folder doesn't exist. You need to provide more info than this.

Comment: POST MORE CODE!!

Comment: added more code

Comment: You should have the declaration `private class DBTask extends AsyncTask<Vehicle,Void,ResponseClass> {` to have the parameters and return type of your `doInBackground()` method. Where is the code where you are writing a file?

Comment: I'm returning ResponseClass object in try statement.

Comment: I omitted the first line with the declaration @Nordii